# emacs keybindings in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: firefox, shortcut-keys, gtk, emacs

I am trying to get Emacs-like Keybindings in GTK, Firefox, Chrome, etc.  I have followed the directions recommended [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Emacs_Keybindings_%28Firefox%29) (and in lots of places) but to no effect.

In other words, I added `gtk-key-theme-name = "Emacs"` to my `.gtkrc-2.0`, and I also ran `gconf-editor` and set `/desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_key_theme` to "Emacs".  I even rebooted just for good measure.

I am using an ordinary 12.04 install, with Unity 3D as the desktop environment.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

same problem as you. This worked for me:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme "Emacs"
```

Source: http://situmam.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/emacs-keybidings-in-ubuntu-1204-precise.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: You're a life saver!  I would vote you up if I had the rep for it.  The answer was `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme "Emacs"`

Comment: To return everything back
`$ gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme "Default"`

Comment: It also works on Ubuntu 16.04.