# Emacs-like keybindings system-wide?

Tags: shortcut-keys, system, emacs

Is there a way to set Emacs-like keyboard shortcuts (at least the subset mentioned below) for the whole OS? This is possible in some apps such as the terminal, Emacs (go figure :) and additionally through special plugins in some other apps (Eclipse), but I got so used to C-f-ing through text and never having to jump to arrows that I'd like to be able to do this system-wide so that I can do it whenever I'm typing - e.g. searching for songs in Rhythmbox, typing stuff into the dash or the HUD, writing mails in Thunderbird or Gmail... The combos I'm most interested in are:

- C-f - forward
- C-b - backwards
- C-a - home
- C-e - end
- C-d - delete
- C-k - delete line

*(note for non-emacs users - C means Ctrl)*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by using [AutoKey](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/autokey-gtk/), as recommended in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/11388/6418). Some of my phrases are:

```
content                     |   hotkey             |   description
---------------------------------------------------------------
<ctrl>+f                    |   <ctrl>+<alt>+f     | replace the find operation
<home>                      |   <ctrl>+a           | begining of line
<end>                       |   <ctrl>+e           | end of line
<left>                      |   <ctrl>+b           | back one letter
<right>                     |   <ctrl>+f           | forward one letter
<delete>                    |   <ctrl>+d           | delete one letter
<home><shift>+<end><delete> |   <ctrl>+k           | kill line
```

(yeah, the kill line combo was nasty to find :)

You could go on replacing stuff, but I don't want the mental remap to grow to large (e.g. ctrl+n doesn't open a new window, but goes to next line). All in all AutoKey is a cool app!

Anyway, now I've got the emacs ergonomy of never having to leave the "letter keys" throughout Ubuntu - in every text box I am editing. Yeiii!

**Update:** as I got deeper into playing with AutoKey to fine-tune everything, I made quite some changes. You can see my complete AutoKey Ubuntu-Emacs configuration (and install it) in my [dotfiles git repo](https://github.com/kermit666/dotfiles/tree/master/autokey).

Comment: So I tried the forward one word <alt>+f but it kept clashing with opening a file in emacs. Did you face that problem? how did you solved it?

Answer (score 26):

Based on: https://superuser.com/a/516847/205010

1. Install gnome-tweak-tool: `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool`
2. Open it: `gnome-tweak-tool`
3. Go to `Keyboard and Mouse` and change `Key Theme` to `Emacs`

Comment: this is pretty cool, but lots of stuff doesn't work, i.e. C-b, C-k etc. the solution is probably pulling everything into emacs, i.e. browser, email etc. rather than trying to push the key bindings out beyond emacs

Comment: Where does it not working? In my case it works most of the time pretty well.

Comment: It seems that if an app implements an equivalent shortcut then that takes precedence. Which is awkward

Comment: I don't think it happens for all apps. I encountered in Chrome a few times that the global Emacs shortcuts took precedence over the specific web app shortcuts.

Comment: my test case was using yahoo mail and gmail in a firefox browser. in both cases C-a C-e C-f C-p C-n worked as expected, but C-b toggled bold font, and C-k brought up a link dialog. So for my particular application it is a bit hit and miss - i'll have to give chrome a try and see if its any different

Comment: @bph: you can unmap default FF keybindings using the https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/s3menu-wizard/ add-in.  This has enabled me to unmap the default FF bindings for CTRL+U and CTRL+K so I can erase the content of the search field without loosing the clipboard!

Comment: This will not work if your running `emacs -nw`

Comment: 2022: in "Tweaks" it's under "Keyboard" and called "Emacs Input", second in a short list of toggles/controls.

Answer (score 6):

There is another solution not involving third-party apps posted here [emacs keybindings in ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181532/emacs-keybindings-in-ubuntu-12-04/181671#181671)

Comment: Using this method will not work in applications such as Thunderbird, where Ctrl+F will be interpreted as "Find String" rather than "Move Cursor Forward".

Comment: @holocronweaver true indeed, I have given up on getting Emacs keys working in Thunderbird sadly, but most of the other inputs (notably in Chrome) almost work. I can't help but feel that the AutoKey solution is road to never ending fiddling and frustration too :) That said have you tried the solution proposed by kermit666 and if so - did it work for you?

Comment: After a bit of editing to make it suit my tastes, the AutoKey solution has worked fairly well in Firefox and Thunderbird on Ubuntu 14.04.  Still more testing to do.

Answer (score 0):

`gnome-tweak-tool` has been replaced with `gnome-tweaks`:

1. Install *gnome-tweaks*: `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweaks`.
2. Open it: `gnome-tweaks`.
3. Go to *Keyboard & Mouse* and switch *Emacs Input* on.