# emacs commands system wide like in mac

Tags: shortcut-keys, system, emacs

I am used to a macOS where I have default basic emacs commands in every text input field. Additionally there exists the option of adding desired emacs commands by adding a `keybinding.dict` file in `~/Library/Keybindings/`. This procedure is described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html).

I know there is the option of using `gnome-tweak-tools` as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/663822/968718). However, this doesn't work perfect as not every text input respects this and it also conflicts with short cuts i.e. firefox, thunderbird etc, since `CTRL` is mainly used for short cuts unlike in macOS.

Is there a way to create a new key (that I can map for example on `Caps Lock`) that I can use instead of `CTRL` for emacs commands to avoid conflicts?

Or at least create two keybindings such that I can switch between emacs keybinding for text input and "normal" keybinding for application short cuts.

Or is there any option to obtain system-wide emacs commands in any input field that is comparable to the situation in macOS?