# How to go to beginning and end of line in ordinary text boxes

Tags: shortcut-keys

When I'm not in vim, how do I go to the beginning of a line in something like Firefox search bar or Google Docs with a keyboard shortcut? How would I replicate macOS's command + arrow keybind.

I'm in 20.04.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally use the <kbd>Home</kbd> key to move to the beginning of input field and <kbd>End</kbd> key to move to the end.

You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + arrow key to move direction one word at a time. For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Left Arrow to move to previous word.

Comment: It surprises me that there are still people unaware of this. These keys have been on keyboards for like 30 years, haven't they?
To add to this answer: In case OP is using one of those compact keyboards without Home and End keys, he can still use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + UP and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + DOWN to go to the end and start of the textfield respectively. 
(Note that this only works on single-line textboxes and not multiline fields like the ones used on SO)

Comment: @Opifex The OP knows how to do it on a MAC or VIM which I don't know how to. I couldn't find an on-line source in Ubuntu or Gnome for `Home` and `End` keys. Microsoft has on-line documentation that incorectly states `Home` moves to the end of the line: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/using-your-keyboard-18b2efc1-9e32-ba5a-0896-676f9f3b994f

Comment: Ever wondered a lot of keyboards these days don't have a `home` and `end` key? You might wanna updated your answer referring this -> https://askubuntu.com/a/1363505/703469

Answer (score 1):

In most applications you can use Emacs-style cursor motion commands:

- beginning-of-line = <kbd>Control-a</kbd>
- end-of-line = <kbd>Control-e</kbd>

Comment: Not only that -- you can also use system-wide tweaks for this to work by default in many places, e.g., https://askubuntu.com/questions/245746/emacs-like-keybindings-system-wide