# Emacs keybindings in Lubuntu

Tags: lubuntu, emacs, shortcut-keys

Is there a way to enable ubiquitous emacs keybindings in Lubuntu?

I've seen solutions for Ubuntu and Xubuntu, such as [emacs keybindings in ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181532/emacs-keybindings-in-ubuntu-12-04/181671#181671), but I haven't found one for Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

On my Lubuntu 14.04, the c-space keybinding seemed to be disabled in emacs. For this particular case you may find solutions in

[ibus breaks emacs and eclipse control-space keybinding](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1278569).

The keybinding seems to be used by ibus instead. You may disable this by adding the line

ibus exit

to your ~/.config/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart.